# jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Message [Auth fail]]

Tags: jenkins

When I am trying to establish a connection from jenkins to the target server .I am getting the below error. I tried generating the keys newly and tried copying the id_rsa.pub to authorized keys still its not working. is there knoWN_hosts file is neccessary to establish a ssh connection..Bcause my server is missed with the knowN_hosts file. Please provide ur comments

**jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection Message: [Failed to connect session for config]. Message [Auth fail]]**

Answer (score 1):

The `known_hosts` file is required to connect to remote host wia Jenkins. **When you try to ssh to remote server through command line, this prompt you to asking for adding this remote server to `known_hosts`.** When you answer this prompt with 'Yes', the `known_hosts` file will be created automatically in `~/.ssh` folder.

Then, you can connect to remote server from Jenkins UI directly.

Answer (score 0):

I've got:

```
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [myproj]. Message [USERAUTH fail]]]
```

and attempt to connect independently with the priv key:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_test user@host
```

revealed that my priv key was encrypted and so I didn't supply password in SSH publishing plugin settings...